# How to add a Reaction to a Specific message discord.py

Tags: python, discord

Im new to Programming and i want to code a reaction role bot, but how can i add a reaction to a specific message with a Message ID, i cant figure that out. Can someone maybe help me?
Mathis

Comment: Try including what you have tried, and where exactly you are stuck to get answers easily.

Comment: next time, i will do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by saving that message id and checking for it in `on_reaction_add`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
   with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
       data = json.load(f)
   if reaction.message.id, reaction.message.guild in data.keys():
      role_id = data[(reaction.message.id, reaction.message.guild]
      role = await reaction.message.guild.get_role(role_id)
      await user.add_roles(role)


@client.command
async def create_react_role(ctx, msg_id: int, role: discord.Role):
     with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
         data = json.load(f)
     data[(msg_id, ctx.guild.id)] = role.id
     with open('data'json', 'w') as f:
         json.dump(data, f, indent = 4)
     await ctx.send('created react role')
```

Note: if you want to give more roles for different reaction emoji, get that as a param in the command and add it in the tuple as a key.

### References:

- [discord.Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.Role)
- [add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [on_reaction_add](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.on_reaction_add)